# Hypercube and affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, hypercube

We have an affine subspace $A$ of dimension $d_{A}$ and a hypercube $C$ of dimension $d_{C}$ ($d_{C}=n$), with $d_{A}\lt d_{C}$ and both belong to $\Re ^{n}$. Each face of dimension $d_{C}-1$ of $C$ has at least an interior point in common with $A$.

The question is: is there any vertex of $C$ that belongs to $A$?

Comment: [This picture](https://gurmeet.net/Images/cube_hexagon.gif) shows that the answer is no, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: What do ypu mean? The counterexample still applies!